# How to pass a interface as a parameter to a method C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, smartcard

I am doing a project in Xamarin android and I'm following a java sample code to connect a smartcard reader (Acr1255u-j1) to android via Bluetooth , and I came acrros a method :

```
mManager.startScan(BluetoothTerminalManager.TERMINAL_TYPE_AMR220_C,
                   new BluetoothTerminalManager.TerminalScanCallback()
{
  @Override public void onScan(final CardTerminal terminal)
  {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
      @Override public void run()
      {
        mTerminalAdapter.addTerminal(terminal);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and the second parameter to the startscan method is a interface " BluetoothTerminalManager.TerminalScanCallback()" but when i try to  convert it to c# it  shows this error:
[erorr on c# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jnI3.png)

Comment: In Java, that's one way they implement callbacks/events, via what they call an [anonymous class implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).  In c#, you typically use lambdas.  But without knowing what the C# version of the class you are calling looks like, we can't really help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do inline interface implementation in C#, you need to either have a class implementation for the interface or if you can adjust the method make it so it accepts a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) or [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0) or [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: To clarify this answer: Probably `ITerminalScanCallback` has a single member, that looks like a function call. If so, and `mManager.startScan` is calling a method that you have source for, then you can eliminate ITerminalScanCallback; replace it with a single function (via delegate, Action, or Func). If not, then you'll need to create `class MyTerminalScanCallback : ITerminalScanCallback`, and implement that interface. Then you can do `new MyTerminalScanCallback()`.